# Fiona schema property name length

Tags: python, fiona, schema

Is it possible to increase property name length in schema?
If I define schema like this:

```
my_schema = { 'geometry': 'Point', 
 'properties': {'Here is very long property name': 'float:12.3'}
```

And in QGIS I see this:

[image]

This property has 10 symbols length. Can't figure out how to increase it.

Comment: You have probably created a shapefile layer. Use some other format that supports longer field names.

Comment: @user30184, yes, you are right. I've created *.shp file.
with fiona.open(shp_pth+"map.shp", 'w',crs=from_epsg(4326),
                    driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=myschema) as output:
But I have to get *.shp file for next task. And manually I can create property with any length with QGIS. But this doesn't work with fiona...

Comment: I do not know how do you create the properties with QGIS but when you save your data into shapefile the field names are cut/converted to max 10 characters as described here https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#creation-issues.

Comment: @user30184, ok I got it. I can create any length property, but after saving I've got only 10 symbols. Thought something wrong with fiona, but it's just *.shp structure.
Thanks for helping to figure out. Gonna try to rename my properties.